# Allure report is not generated after Selenium+Specflow+Nunit tests had executed

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, allure, nunit-3.0

Created a simple framework with Scenario Outline tests, it can be found [here](https://github.com/Ukrainis/SeleniumSpecflowAllureTest). Copied allureConfig.json file into bin/debug directory. Nuget versions:

```
Nunit 3.9.0;
SpecFlow 2.3.0;
SpecFlow.Allure 2.2.0.11;
Net framework 4.6.2.
```

After tests execution, using search, I found test-results directory in the next location:

```
C:\Users\Valentins\AppData\Local\Temp\allure-results
```

And it contains just .json files, like:

```
52bb84abaec342e1bf8e7fbc3e46a181-container
```

and

```
9ab91b6fc6e84eafbda735c49ccfcb1c-result
```

Can anyone help to understand, how to make this folder to appear in the tests and how to normally open Test results to see it in Html file?

Thanks in advance,
Valentins.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was running tests, using Visual Studio. When I started to run, using CI server (TeamCity), then allure-results folder appeared in the Project, but for creating a report, `allure-commandline-tools` were needed.